# How to fix "autoload.php failed to open stream " error, while installing Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Warning:require(C:\xampp\htdocs\cms-3.0\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

I am working on **xampp** as + with the composer installed on Win8.1.

Below is the error I get when I want to install a project with Laravel.

```
Warning:require(C:\xampp\htdocs\cms-3.0\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

Comment: Try with command `composer update`,  if not works then try with `composer update --no-scripts` Hope above method will fix the issue

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What **exactly** do you mean b y"when I want to install a project"?

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `composer install` or `composer update` in your project root directory